# Using sed or awk to extract the lines between 2 patterns

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am new to shell scripting and tried lot many things using old threads to retrieve the message from the log file but failed to get the desired output.

Below is the sample message how it looks

```
00:31:54.184 MNK  I 4155809232 (monklog:391): The result of the mapping is : S|aaaaa|bbbbb|32|D|M|28/04/2015|ccc|33208369
00:31:54.184 MNK  I 4155809232 (monklog:391): .05|28/04/2015|0428|C|105840.|dddd|fffff|9511705558|/CTC/097/eeeeee eee|/PT
00:31:54.184 MNK  I 4155809232 (monklog:391): /SC/TT/12/SN/eee eeeeeee/CeeY/ee -eee aa aaaa S.A.B. DE C.V./DC/aaaaa
00:31:54.184 MNK  I 4155809232 (monklog:391):  AND aaaaa aaaa/NA/aaaaa,/SK/aaaaa|D|M|28/04/2015|MXN|11111.17||||
00:31:54.184 MNK  I 4155809232 (monklog:391): ||||ssssss|ssssss|qwerrt-aaaaaa|ggggggg||||||||||||||||
00:31:54.184 MNK  I 4155809232 (monklog:391): S|aaaaa|bbbbb|32|D|M|28/04/2015|ccc|33208369
00:31:54.184 MNK  I 4155809232 (monklog:391): .05|28/04/2015|0428|C|105840.|dddd|fffff|9511705558|/CTC/097/eeeeee eee|/PT
00:31:54.184 MNK  I 4155809232 (monklog:391): /SC/TT/12/SN/eee eeeeeee/CeeY/ee -eee aa aaaa S.A.B. DE C.V./DC/aaaaa
00:31:54.184 MNK  I 4155809232 (monklog:391):  AND aaaaa aaaa/NA/aaaaa,/SK/aaaaa|D|M|28/04/2015|MXN|11111.17||||
00:31:54.184 MNK  I 4155809232 (monklog:391): ||||ssssss|ssssss|qwerrt-aaaaaa|ggggggg||||||||||||||||
00:31:54.184 MNK  I 4155809232 (monklog:406): ||29/04/2015 01:31:00|||||||||^M
```

I need to get the message from **S|** and before **^M**.

I tried these codes.

```
awk '/S|/{flag=1}/|^M/{flag=0}flag' $Log  > output2.txt
sed -n '/: S|/,/|^M/p' $Log > output.txt
```

Both gives me same input as output. Please help. Thanks.

---

#### Expected output

```
S|aaaaa|bbbbb|32|D|M|28/04/2015|ccc|33208369.05|28/04/2015|0428|C|105840.|dddd|fffff|9511705558|/CTC/097/eeeeee eee|/PT/SC/TT/12/SN/eee eeeeeee/CeeY/ee -eee aa aaaa S.A.B. DE C.V./DC/aaaaa AND aaaaa aaaa/NA/aaaaa,/SK/aaaaa|D|M|28/04/2015|MXN|11111.17||||||||ssssss|ssssss|qwerrt-aaaaaa|ggggggg||||||||||||||||
S|aaaaa|bbbbb|32|D|M|28/04/2015|ccc|33208369.05|28/04/2015|0428|C|105840.|dddd|fffff|9511705558|/CTC/097/eeeeee eee|/PT/SC/TT/12/SN/eee eeeeeee/CeeY/ee -eee aa aaaa S.A.B. DE C.V./DC/aaaaa AND aaaaa aaaa/NA/aaaaa,/SK/aaaaa|D|M|28/04/2015|MXN|11111.17||||||||ssssss|ssssss|qwerrt-aaaaaa|ggggggg||||||||||||||||
```

Each set should come in single line.

Comment: It is not obvious to me what your expected output is. Could you please add it to the question?

Comment: In your awk attempt, you need to change `S|` to `S\|`, as the pipe is interpreted as a regex OR.

Comment: What about the first line that contains S|

Comment: @TomFenech , I changed like this awk '/S\|/{flag=1}/\|^M/{flag=0}flag' $Log but still i get the complete input as output.

Comment: If you're new to shell programming, @sundar, you may want to invest your energy in learning Python or Perl, which would solve anything that AWK or SED would, in a more robust way. AWK and SED are more suitable (IMO) to one liners than to more complicated tasks as you defined in your OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you like?

```
awk -F"): " '{$0=$NF} /^S\|/ {f=1} /\^M/ {f=0} f' file
S|aaaaa|bbbbb|32|D|M|28/04/2015|ccc|33208369
.05|28/04/2015|0428|C|105840.|dddd|fffff|9511705558|/CTC/097/eeeeee eee|/PT
/SC/TT/12/SN/eee eeeeeee/CeeY/ee -eee aa aaaa S.A.B. DE C.V./DC/aaaaa
 AND aaaaa aaaa/NA/aaaaa,/SK/aaaaa|D|M|28/04/2015|MXN|11111.17||||
||||ssssss|ssssss|qwerrt-aaaaaa|ggggggg||||||||||||||||
```

Not sure what  `S|` you like to start with. You have one in line `1` and one in line `6` (Both with same data after)

Comment: Let me clear the requirement further. This is a sample file from server logs. Ideally the content will be different but only unique pattern in the data is S| and ^M. So would like to get the content using these pattern for entire log file and each unique set should be in single line. We will feed this as input payload to SOA services and it is required for data recovery.

Comment: @sundars So you like to get all lines where data (after `(monklog:391):`) starts with `|S`, and until line ends with `^M` but not line itself.  If so, my solution should do.

Comment: Making a huge assumption that `):` will not appear in the end part.

Comment: Or guess the width is fixed.  Both is user assumption.

Comment: @jotne Ok, I got it. It give only 2 occurrence if it has 3 set for example. it skips the last set. is this expected? How to get that as well. Also all lines that start and end within pattern should be in single line.

Comment: The end has random data, but every line the field starts in the same place. But i suppose we would need OP to confirm whether both are valid :)

Comment: ): will never appear in the end part but width of the content between pattern is not fixed. But it will always starts S| and end with ^M

Comment: @sundars If you have 10 `|S` `^M` par, it will print 10 group of output.  To separate the group, you can use: `awk -F"): " '{$0=$NF} /^S\|/ {f=1;print "part #"++c"\n-------"} /\^M/ {f=0} f' file`

Comment: @Jotne, I am not sure what is missing, but i changed the data and came to know that it skips first pattern. so if it has 3 set, it give only part1, part2 as it skips first match. Sorry to drag this.

Comment: @Jotne, How to include last line as well. In your output, last line is missing - ||29/04/2015 01:31:00|||||||||^M?

Comment: @sundars Just swap the test/print around `awk -F"): " '{$0=$NF} /^S\|/ {f=1} f; /\^M/ {f=0}' file`  If you like the answer, you can accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

This works for your exact specifications of input and output

```
awk '{$0=substr($0,47)}/^S\|/{x=1}/\^M$/{x=0}x' file

S|aaaaa|bbbbb|32|D|M|28/04/2015|ccc|33208369
.05|28/04/2015|0428|C|105840.|dddd|fffff|9511705558|/CTC/097/eeeeee eee|/PT
/SC/TT/12/SN/eee eeeeeee/CeeY/ee -eee aa aaaa S.A.B. DE C.V./DC/aaaaa
 AND aaaaa aaaa/NA/aaaaa,/SK/aaaaa|D|M|28/04/2015|MXN|11111.17||||
||||ssssss|ssssss|qwerrt-aaaaaa|ggggggg||||||||||||||||
```

Comment: Hi, this works as expected but how to get it recursively for entire file and it should come in single line within the patterns that is searched. How the substr makes the difference..?

Comment: It gives only first occurrence and also in multiple lines.could please recheck it?

Comment: It works for what you posted, and will work for similar data. Please post the data it doesn't work for in the question.

Comment: @Jotne Deleting my account soon so changed my name to blank.

Comment: We then can not use the @ to trigger your name when posting comment in others post.

Comment: @Jotne Other people have been doing ?

Answer (score 0):

`sed` based approach:

```
$ sed -n '/S\|/,/\^M/{

           /S\|/  {s/.*S|/S|/};
                  {s/.*[0-9]\+): //;H}
           /\^M/  {g;s/\n//g;s/\^M.*//p;};

       }' file.log
S|aaaaa|bbbbb|32|D|M|28/04/2015|ccc|33208369.05|28/04/2015|0428|C|105840.|dddd|fffff|9511705558|/CTC/097/eeeeee eee|/PT/SC/TT/12/SN/eee eeeeeee/CeeY/ee -eee aa aaaa S.A.B. DE C.V./DC/aaaaa AND aaaaa aaaa/NA/aaaaa,/SK/aaaaa|D|M|28/04/2015|MXN|11111.17||||||||ssssss|ssssss|qwerrt-aaaaaa|ggggggg||||||||||||||||S|aaaaa|bbbbb|32|D|M|28/04/2015|ccc|33208369.05|28/04/2015|0428|C|105840.|dddd|fffff|9511705558|/CTC/097/eeeeee eee|/PT/SC/TT/12/SN/eee eeeeeee/CeeY/ee -eee aa aaaa S.A.B. DE C.V./DC/aaaaa AND aaaaa aaaa/NA/aaaaa,/SK/aaaaa|D|M|28/04/2015|MXN|11111.17||||||||ssssss|ssssss|qwerrt-aaaaaa|ggggggg||||||||||||||||00|||||||||
```

Explanation:

1. For lines between `S|` & `^M` - `'/S\|/,/\^M/{`
2. If line contains `S|`, remove everything till `S|` - `/S\|/{s/.*S|/S|/};`
3. Remove everything till `<digits>):` & append the remaining string to hold space -  `{s/.*[0-9]\+): //;H}`. This removes the prefix text like `00:31:54.184 MNK  I 4155809232 (monklog:391):`
4. For lines matching `^M`, copy entire hold space to pattern space. Remove newlines (which had got added because of `H` command. Remove everything after `^M` & print. - `/\^M/  {g;s/\n//g;s/\^M.*//p;};`

Similar logic using `awk`:

```
$ awk -v FS="[0-9]+): " '
     /S\|/ && (!a){  a = a gensub(/.*S\|/,"S|","",$2); next;}
     /\^M/ && a { print a gensub(/\^M.*/,"","",$2); a=0;}
     a{a=a $2};
     ' file.log
```

Comment: this is not working when it has anyother entries before the actual content that needs to be parsed. Say there is one line above like 00:31:54.184 MNK  I 4155809232 (monklog:391): Error data to same input. What happens with this code is it truncates the prefix and merges Error data to all line that it filters

Comment: And if I use awk logic, it retrieves other lines that ends ^M. Like 00:31:54.178 MNK  I 4155809232 (monklog:406): Message to translation is : ^M, it retrieves Message to translation is : along with actual message that is expected.Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the modified code but still i have one problem. It prints additional 0 in each line like 0S|0072945957 except first set.

Comment: In your expected output, you have 2 lines. but your sample input only has one `^M` So shouldn't the output contain only one line?